# Duda Ej. Python

Tags: python, while

Como podria incorporar a este programa de adivinar una palabra la declaración Break? :

```
palabracorrecta = "Chupacabra"
palabra = ""
condicion = False
while palabra != palabracorrecta and not condicion == True:
        palabra = input("Ingrese la palabra : ")
        

if condicion:
    print()
else:
    print("¡Has dejado el ciclo con éxito!")
```

Comment: Solo haz el `while True` dentro de este verificar si la palabra es correcta, en caso lo sea pones el `break`

Comment: Evita los títulos de tipo _duda con..._, _problema con..._, etc. En su lugar, pulsa en [edit] y escribe cuál es el problema que estás teniendo.

Comment: Ok lo voy a tener en cuenta entonces muchas gracias

Comment: Haz preguntado por dudas en `break`, `continue`, `sleep` ... será mejor que estudies un tutorial de Python.

Answer (score 0):

Algo así:

```
palabracorrecta = "Chupacabra"
palabra = ""
#condicion = False
while True: #palabra != palabracorrecta: and not condicion == True:
        palabra = input("Ingrese la palabra : ")
        if palabra!=palabracorrecta:
            print()            
        else:
            print("¡Has dejado el ciclo con éxito!")
            break
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Ese `print` dentro del `if` estorba, si no quieres colocar nada usa `pass`